# A chart-independent way to identify tangent spaces to a Euclidean submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, tangent-bundle

Suppose $S\subset \Bbb R^n$ is a $k$-submanifold, is there a chart-independent (or "natural") way to identify $T_xS$ to a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ for each $x\in S$?

If we let $\iota: S\to \Bbb R^n$ be the inclusion map, then I think we can naturally identify $T_xS$ with $d(\iota)_xT_xS$, a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Thing is, how to determine $d(\iota)_xT_xS$ chart-independently?

A chart-dependent way is to impose a chart $(\phi,U)$ about $x$, and $T_xS$ is spanned by $$\hat\partial_i=\left(C_x^\infty(S)\ni f\mapsto \frac\partial{\partial x_i}\Big|_{\phi(x)}f\circ\phi^{-1}\in\Bbb R\right),\quad i=1,\cdots,k$$
whose image under $d(\iota)_x$ is
\begin{align}
d(\iota)_x(\hat\partial_i) 
&=\left(C^\infty_x(\Bbb R^n)\ni g\mapsto \hat\partial_i \left(g\circ \iota\right)\in\Bbb R\right)\\
&= \left(C^\infty_x(\Bbb R^n)\ni g\mapsto \frac\partial{\partial x_i}\Big|_{\phi(x)} \left(g\circ \iota\circ\phi^{-1}\right)\in\Bbb R\right)\\
&=\left(C^\infty_x(\Bbb R^n)\ni g\mapsto \frac\partial{\partial x_i}\Big|_{\phi(x)} \left(g\circ\phi^{-1}\right)\in\Bbb R\right)\\
\end{align}
And I get stuck at:

1). It looks quite hard to find a neat coordinate representation $d(\iota)_x(\hat\partial_i)=x^i\partial_i\in T_x\Bbb R^n=\Bbb R^n$ where $\partial_i$ is the standard partial derivative in the $i$-th component.

2). The dependence on $\phi$ seems unable to be unravelled.

So, I wonder: is there a way to determine the coordinate representation of $d(\iota)_xT_xS$ in $\Bbb R^n$ only via $x$ and not depending on $\phi$?

---

**Update** Actually from 
$$d(\iota)_x(\hat\partial_i) = \left(C^\infty_x(\Bbb R^n)\ni g\mapsto \frac\partial{\partial x_i}\Big|_{\phi(x)} \left(g\circ \iota\circ\phi^{-1}\right)\in\Bbb R\right)$$
I could have obtained $d(\iota)_x(\hat\partial_i) =\sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\Big|_{\phi(x)}(\iota\circ\phi^{-1})^j\partial_j$. 
And furthermore, we can see that the basis of $d(\iota)_xT_xS$ (identified in $\Bbb R^n$) is obtained by stacking these together as the columns of $D(\iota\circ\phi^{-1})|_{\phi(x)}$ where $D$ denotes the standard Jacobian matrix.

So my first question is in a sense solved. The remaining part is to undo the inpendence upon $\phi$.

---

**Update 2** To undo the dependence on chart, we have only to show that given any two chart $\phi,\psi$ about $x$, $D(\iota\circ\phi^{-1})|_{\phi(x)}$ and $D(\iota\circ\psi^{-1})|_{\psi(x)}$ **has the same column space**. This observation may help solve the problem.

---

**Update 3 (Problem totally solved)** Okay guys I think I've been on the right track. The final observation is that 
$$D(\iota\circ\psi^{-1})|_{\psi(x)}=D(\iota\circ\phi^{-1})|_{\phi(x)}D(\phi\circ\psi^{-1})|_{\psi(x)}$$
in which $D(\phi\circ\psi^{-1})|_{\psi(x)}$ is clearly invertible since $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism, this is sufficient to make the two indicated column spaces coincide. So my problem has been totally solved! But still many thanks to you guys who've been paying attention.

Answer (score 3):

A chart independent definition of $T_x S$ is the set of all vectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which there exists a smooth curve $\gamma : (-1,+1) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $\gamma(t) \in S$ for all $t \in (-1,+1)$
2. $\gamma(0)=x$
3. $\frac{d\gamma}{dt} \bigm|_{t=0} = v$

Comment: Thanks for your help. However what I really want is to show $T_xS$ can be spanned from the columns of $\mathbb BA_x$ where $\mathbb B$ is a fixed basis in $\Bbb R^n$ and $A_x$ is a matrix varying smoothly in $x$ (that's why I'm looking for a coordinate representation). In fact, the context is I'm trying to show the Gaussian map $x\mapsto d(\iota)_xT_xS$ into the Grassmannian $G_{k,n-k}$ is smooth. For what it's worth, the observation I just made i.e. $d(\iota)_xT_xS = D(\iota\circ\phi^{-1})|_{\phi(x)}$ has shown that the Gauss map is pointwise smooth.

Comment: ...But of course, I have yet to undo the chart dependence to show the Gauss map is globally well-defined on $S$.